# Create association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, associations

I've got model Project and model User. I've got belongs_and_has_many in these. But now I need to tell Rails: this *specific* user belongs to this *specific* project. How can I do it in Project controller, and how can I call this method from project view? Thank you very much.

in project's**show.html.erb** I ve got:

```
<select id="user_select" name="user_select" class="input-large">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <option><%= user.username %></options>
  <% end %>
</select>
<!-- button to addfriend method here -->
```

And I need to call method "addfriend" from here with parameter from selection to associated project with this user :-/

Method **addfiend** in project controller:

```
def addfriend
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
      @project.users << User.find(params[:user])
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to project, :notice => 'Added.' }
      end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If in model project, you have `has_and_belongs_to_many :users`, you project object has an [implicit collection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association), users, that can be added to like any other collection, e.g.:

```
project.users << User.find(:first, :conditions => "name = 'foo'")
```

Comment: Is "<<" same as "=" ?? What if Ill write project.users = User.find(params[:user] ?

Comment: No, it's not. `<<` appends to an array, `=` replaces it.

Comment: So I can make in project controller:
`def methodXX
  project = Project.find(params[:id])
  project.users << User.find(params[:user])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to project, :notice => 'Added.' }
end`

And in routes set this method path.
Right?

Answer (score 0):

This would look something like that in your controller action:

```
@project = Project.create(:user_id => user_id)
```

while user_id is your foreign key (something you would probably want to pass from your view).

This code will be written in some controller action, and you would have to define a route for connecting a URL to this action.

Notice that once you call the action that runs this code you can access @project from your view.

You can read about routes [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).
You can read about mvc in rails [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).
You can read about associations here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Will Project.create create new project or not? I dont want to create new one, I just want to make only association between project and user.

Comment: project = Project.find(params[:id])
project.users << User.find(params[:user])